# How to check which permissions I have as an IAM user

Tags: amazon-web-services, cloud, amazon-iam

I'm totally new to AWS and learning about IAM. I was wondering if there is a way around for an IAM user to check what all permission he/she have? Like as a root user, I created a group of IAM users where they were only allowed to use S3 service but once I logged in as an IAM user, it was showing that I have access to other AWS services as well like running EC2 instances, etc which I reckon shouldn't be the case. Thanks!

Comment: Console shows everything. If you had tried to actually launch instance you would probably encountered an error. Maybe AWS Policy Simulator can be used for testing IAM user permissions?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

No, it isn't possible to "show" which services you have access to use, because the policies can be quite complex (eg permission to access an S3 bucket, but only a particular sub-folder if coming from a given range of IP addresses).

You would need to look the the IAM Policies attached to the IAM User, plus the policies on any IAM Groups they are in. Then, some services like Amazon S3 have additional permissions such as Bucket Policies.

In addition, AWS Organizations can limit the permissions of *all users* within an AWS Account, so even if a user appears to be granted certain permissions, they might not actually be available for use.

In many situations, you'll only know if you can do something by actually *trying it*. For example, you might have Read Only permissions, which means you can see resources in the AWS Console, but you would receive an error when you try to change things.

All services are available in the AWS Console, but various parts of the console will only work if you have adequate permission.

Comment: AWS permissions are such a nightmare. Why does it have to be some complex and difficult?

Answer (score 3):

Note that there's [IAM Policy Simulator](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/IAM/latest/UserGuide/access_policies_testing-policies.html) from AWS. You can select a service and check if a given user has access to any given action (or all actions relevant to a service)